# getting values from WriteResult mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I was trying to get familiar with the WriteResult object in mongo, but I can't access any of its values. The docs say the number of values inserted is stored in WriteResult.nInserted. Trying to access nInserted is crashing my server.

```
var readings = new Readings({
    val1: parseInt(Data[0]),
    val2: parseInt(Data[1]),
    val3: parseInt(Data[2]),
    val4: parseInt(Data[3]),
    val5: parseInt(Data[4]),
    val6: parseInt(Data[5]),
})
var result = readings.save(function (err, post){
    if(err){return next(err)}
    res.status(201).json(readings)
})
if(result.nInserted > 0){
    console.log('wrote to database')
}
else{
    console.log('could not write to database')
}
```

I know the data is being written to the database. I see it in the mongo shell.

Comment: What is `readings`?  Is that a Mongoose doc?

Comment: @JohnnyHK It's the object I'm creating a document out of. I have updated the post to include it.

Comment: Thanks, but then what is `Readings`? :)  Is that a Mongoose model?

Comment: yes, that was set with db.model('Readings', {//values in here})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`save`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) method on a model instance doesn't return anything.  All results are reported via the callback method, so you'd use something like this:

```js
readings.save(function (err, doc, numberAffected){
    if(err){return next(err)}
    if (numberAffected > 0) {
        console.log('updated an existing doc');
    } else {
        console.log('added a new doc');
    }
    res.status(201).json(doc)
})
```

Mongoose doesn't give you access to the full `WriteResult`, but as long as `err` is null you can rest assured the `save` succeeded and it's only a matter of whether an existing doc was updated or a new one was added.  Because you're creating a new doc here, `numberAffected` will always be 0.

Comment: is there another parameter I can pass to the callback to capture the number of created documents, just in case that might be useful in the future? Also, I have the if statement to capture errors, but where would a hypothetical error be returned to? What happens with it?

Comment: `err` contains full details on any error, and `save` can never insert more than one doc.

Comment: right, but will the error automatically be printed to console (broweser or server) or can it crash the server?

Comment: It all depends on what you do with the error. As long as you don't throw it yourself it won't crash your server.  If you want it logged to the console you need to do it yourself.